# Presto split string, but output to a new line

Tags: presto

Sorry if question is vague.

I have a string that I want to format in a certain way

[Currently it gets outputted like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZyZE.png)

[Could I output this like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl8aF.png)
With a new line for after each deliminator?

The common deliminator is the pipe (|) for these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of the [`split()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#split) function to turn the strings into arrays of elements, and [`UNNEST`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest), to convert each element in the array into a separate row:

```sql
WITH t(column, text) AS (
    VALUES
        ('column1', 'text1|text2|text3'),
        ('column2', 'text3|text4|text4')
)
SELECT t.column, u.item
FROM t, UNNEST(split(t.text, '|')) u(item)
```